# How resolve TypeErrors for SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am currently experiencing the following errors, while debugging my client-side code using web-browser:

```
  TypeError: $ is undefined 
  ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

In the in the "Network" tab, of the debugger, it shows the JQueries scripts as "404". Does this indicate my Jqueries are not being render/initialized

This is my client-side code:

```
     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.          
    var notifications = $.connection.NotificationHub;
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    notifications.client.recieveNotification = function (role, descrip) {
        // Add the message to the page.                    
        $('#spanNewMessages').text(role);
        $('#spanNewCircles').text(descrip);

    };
    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        alert("Preparing to send notifications...");
        notifications.server.sendNotifications();
        alert("Notifications have been sent.");

    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
    //$.connection.hub.start();
});
   </script>
   <h1>New Notifications</h1>
   <div>
      New <span id="spanNewMessages"></span> role.<br />
      New<span id="spanNewCircles"></span> descrip.<br /> 
   </div>
```

Updated Jquery Scripts:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Any help would be very helpful.  Thank you

Comment: "_In the in the "Network" tab, of the debugger, it shows the JQueries scripts as "404". Does this indicate my Jqueries are not being render/initialized"_ - Yes. The paths to the scripts are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ is an alias of jQuery. Your jquery script has to be included in your page if you want to use it.

As long as your jQuery script returns 404, you won't be able to use it. To help you, you could load the script from the jQuery website.

Replace this line :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

with this one :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

A good practice on a website is to load jQuery from the Google cdn as it will be most likely cached as many websites use it :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Another thing you can do to ensure that your script will do well is to make sure that there is no conflict with other scripts. Add this at the begining of your code :

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Make sure that you replace every $ with jQuery.

Example :

```
$('#spanNewMessages').text(role);
```

will become :

```
jQuery('#spanNewMessages').text(role);
```

If it does not work, remove all your code and just try to display alert(jQuery("h1").text()); like this :

```
jQuery(function () { alert(jQuery("h1").text()); });
```

Comment: Dear Simon, Thank you for your reply and help.  I changed my scripts according to your suggestion and I still receiving the `typeError`, such as `TypeError: $ is undefined ``TypeError: $.connection is undefined`.  Please advice further, as to where I may be going wrong.

Comment: jquery has to be the 1st script you add in your page!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion and help.  Using your answer as guide, helped me diagnosed my issue and I manage to get the issue resolved.  Many thanks for your time and help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your script tags is wrong. You need to load jquery before jquery.signalr:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all, for your suggestion and help.

I manage to get the issue resolved through using the Scripts as the following below:

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```